# .Net 6 web api FluentValidation Matches regex pattern for lowercase letters, numbers and hyphens

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm testing my API and I'm not able to figure out how this thing works.

I need the Validator to fail when the pattern [z-a0-9-] is matched against all kinds of input, both valid and invalid.

it doesn't seem to work like i think it should work.

my test code:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("62c1a17e6b09e88d43cbb087-transactionreport")]
[InlineData("test-json-20220619324234")]
[InlineData("62c1a17e6b09e88d43cbb087")]
[InlineData("test")]
[InlineData("-json-")]
[InlineData("FileName")]
[InlineData("20220619324234")]
[InlineData("2022--06193--24234")]
public async Task ValidateCreateFileRequest_ReturnTrue(string name)
{
    //Arrange
    var request = new CreateFileRequest { Name = name };
    //Act
    var result = _validator.TestValidate(request);
    //Assert
    result.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(m => m.Name);
}
```

validator code:

```
public CreateFileRequestValidator(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty()
        .NotNull()
        .MinimumLength(3)
        .Matches(configuration["Validations:FileNamePattern"]).WithMessage("File name can contain only lowercase characters, digits and hyphens");
}
```

All these tests pass but one test ("FileName") should NOT pass because it doesn't match the pattern.

it seem like it returns valid when the first match is found. how do i tell the validation to keep matching until it fails?

Comment: What happens when you run the tests? They all pass? Which one is failing?

Comment: they all pass. `[InlineData("FileName")]` should fail

Answer (score 1):

I think your pattern is not correct. try this.

```
^[a-z0-9-]
```

I tried this with a sample app and it fails for "FileName" but passed for all other string you mention in your question.

Comment: not valid =\ but i did solve it with the help of a friend. ill post my answer now

Answer (score 0):

the pattern is "^[a-z0-9-]+$"